Where is the theme.res source file?
Trying to style a side-menu per the developer guide, it tells me that every CodenameOne app has a theme.res file in the src directory, but I do not find one anywhere throughout the project, which I started from the bare-bones Java example app.
The project does have a theme.css file and the app builds and runs ok, with a generated theme.res landing in the target/classes directory (using IntelliJ), and I can make changes to that one that I can see have the desired effect, but that file goes away with a maven clean.  So where is the real source file, that I can alter using the resource file editor?

Codename One moved to CSS for newer maven build processes. As such the CSS generates the res file for you during the build process and updates the res file every time you edit the file (it refreshes the simulator automatically as you save).

Is there a GUI editor for the css file?

It's typically an either/or situation. I suggest moving to CSS which is the way forward. The approach you took in your answer is problematic, it effectively disables the CSS support.

I realize that I am quite late in coming to the CodenameOne party, but as a Java/Swing app developer I have seen that it is my best way to evolve from the desktop to mobile devices.  That said, I am relying heavily on the developer guide, which in light of evolutions such as this one and the deprecation of the Intellij CodenameOne plugin, appears seriously outdated.   Can we expect any updates there?

I started working on that a while back but never completed that. There are a lot of separate documents/videos and the task of updating even a small fraction of that is huge. The guide is open so hopefully a community member will make these changes.

It seems that the answer is that there isn't a theme.res in the example app, other than the one generated during a build.  But I took that one and copied it into my common/src/main/resources directory, and that one is editable using the GUI editor and (after another maven clean) is used by the app.  Also not present in the code generated for me by the web app at start.codenameone.com was the init() method in my main class, which I found in the developer guide and copy/pasted into my main code.  After these actions, I can use the gui editor to edit the theme.res file and see the results in the run of new build.
